# Making a re-useable function of JSON URL fetching function in SWIFT 2.0

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I am stuck in a problem. I think it is all due to my weak basics. I am sure someone can help me easily and put me in the right direction.

I have different segues and all get the data from JSON via remote URL.
So in-short all segues need to open URL and parse JSON and make them into an ARRAY

I have made the first segue and it is working fine.
Now i plan to use the functions where it download JSON and turns it into ARRAY as a common function

I read in another page on stackoverflow that I can declare all common functions outside the class in ViewController

I hope everyone is with me this far.

now in ViewController i declare a function

```
getDataFromJson(url: String)
```

This function code looks like following

```
func getJsonFromURL(url: String)
{
    // some class specific tasks

    // call the common function with URL
    // get an array
    let arrJSON = getJsonArrFromURL(url)

    for element in arrJSON
    {
        // assign each element in json to ur table
        print("Element: \(element)")
    }

    // some class specific tasks
}
```

and this will call the common function declared outside the score of class

```
getArrFromJson(url: String) -> NSArray
```

This common function is just very generic.
Take a URL, call it, open it, parse its data into ARRAY and return it back.

The problem i am stuck is where to put the return
It returns empty array as the task is not finished and i am clueless

```
func getJsonArrFromURL(var url: String) -> NSArray
{
    var parseJSON : NSArray?

    if ( url == "" )
    {
        url = self.baseURLHomepage
    }
    print("Opening a JSON URL \(url)")

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: url);
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);

    request.HTTPMethod = "GET";

    let postString = "";        
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
    {
        data, response, error in

        if ( error != nil )
        {
            print("Error open JSON url \n\(error)")
            return
        }

        do
        {
            parseJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray
        }
        catch
        {
            self.showAlert("Error", msg: "Error occurred while trying to process the product information data")


            print("Error occured in JSON = \(error)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    return parseJSON!

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably add a method like below in any of your class

```
func post(url: String, info: String, completionHandler: (NSString?, NSError?) -> ()) -> NSURLSessionTask {
    let URL = NSURL(string: url)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    let bodyData = info
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            guard data != nil else {
                print("response String is nil")
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                return
            }
            if let dataNew = data {
                 completionHandler(NSString(data: (NSData(base64EncodedData: dataNew, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions([])))!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding), nil)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    return task
}
```

and access it anywhere like

```
    let url = "your URL String"
    let info = "The data you would like to pass"
    yourClassName.post(url, info: info) { responseString, error in
            guard responseString != nil else {
                print("response String is nil")
                print(error)
                return
            }
            do {
                if !(responseString as? String)!.isEmpty {
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData((responseString as! String).data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
                    //process your json here
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error\n \(error)")
                return
            }
        }
```

Extend your string like follows

```
extension String {
    var data:NSData! {
        return dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
}
```

Comment: I can copy paste and i am sure it can work. but it is too complicated for my level. completion handler, guard data etc. Cant my function work with slight editing or you just cant return data from a function which has async task?

Comment: It won't work the way you have coded. dataTaskWithRequest executes in background thread and is initiated when it meets task.resume(). So, your code will actually return null/nil before it completes the dataTask. For more [info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/)

Comment: I am getting this error "value of type 'String' has no member data"

let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData((responseString as! String).data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

Comment: Instead of .data, encode the string as dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Comment: It compiles with this syntax.

let arrJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData((responseString as! String).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

May be you can edit it for the future kids like me who drop by

Comment: as soon as i run, i get the fatal error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

completionHandler(NSString(data: (NSData(base64EncodedData: data!, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions([])))!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding), nil)

Comment: Application Started...
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: same error. even after adding the extension for String
completionHandler(NSString(data: (NSData(base64EncodedData: data!, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions([])))!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding), nil)

Comment: I think your webService is not returning nay data. I changed to safely handle optionals now. Try it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96255/discussion-between-sallu-and-pk20).

Comment: my webservice is returning data fine. my app works fine as long as it is my function it is using. but my function is not generic. i want to use your function as it can be generic.